# How to specify method AnyObject<? super T, String>

Tags: java, generics, jpa

I want to specify a method in an interface the signature of the method of an implementation (JPA 2 based) is:

```
List<T> getByStringValue(SingularAttribute<? super T, String> attribute, String value)
```

I want to specify this method in an interface (`Object<? super T, String>` is not possible) that abstracts from jpa. The implementing method could have a different signature but i want it to accept `SingularAttribute<? super T, String>` and i want to use it in type safe query without casting around.

At the end i want to specify all entity interaction in a "Repository" interface and want to give one JPA-based implementation that covers most of it for all entities (to minimize redundant code). I have finished it for CRUD-ops and getAll. Now i wish i could provide a generic approach for getByCriteria (one Critera is enough at the moment).

Comment: Have a look at Spring's [`CrudReapository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/repository/CrudRepository.html). You are reinventing a wheel.

Comment: thanks, but this part is done and is very simple (is there a jpa 2 based implementation?). But i need a generic approach for queries with criteria.

Comment: It does that. You just declare a method in an interface like `findByNameAndAge(String name, Integer age);` and spring does the rest!

Comment: i need to use pure java ee 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Java doesn't allow the non-generic-parameter part to itself be some kind of wildcard, eg any class that has certain generic parameters:

```
<T> void method(*<T, String> o) // can't do this
```

But you can define an abstract type and have all classes you want to use like this implement it, something like:

```
interface StringGetter<T> {
    T getByStringValue(String value);
}
```

then:

```
public class WidgetStringGetter implements StringGetter<Widget> {
    public Widget getByStringValue(String value) {
        // whatever
    }
}
```

and:

```
public static <T> T factory(StringGetter<T> getter, String value) {
    return getter.getByStringValue(value);
}
```

finally:

```
Widget w = factory(new WidgetStringGetter(), "foo");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following.

```
<R, T extends R> List<T> getByStringValue(SingularAttribute<R, String> attribute, String value)
```

The `<R, T extends R>` defines generic parameters for use in the method signature.

Comment: but i need to substitute "SingularAttribute". i want the method to accept any generic with <R, String>